# How to create a new Ember app with the beta build

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I can create a new Ember app with `ember new my-app`. That uses the stable build.

How can I create a new Ember app with Ember CLI that uses the beta build?

Comment: You can just install the beta build after the project has been generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use beta build in newly generated Ember CLI app you have to:

1. In bower.json, change ember version in dependencies to beta, for example: `"ember": "2.0.0-beta.1"`.
2. Run `bower install`.

However I would suggest to update also versions of Ember Data(**both in bower.json and package.json**) and other addons to avoid deprecations.